# laravel error "ArgumentCountError Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\UserController::messagesend(), 1 passed 2 expected"

Tags: php, html, laravel, performance, laravel-8

I'm trying to send a message to users through their user_id
this is my controller

```
  public function messagesend(Request $request, $user_id){
        $data = array('details'=>$request->details,
        'email' =>$user_id->email);
        Mail::send('transactionmessage', $data, function($message) use ($data){
                $message->from ('test@test.com');
                $message->to($request->email);
                $message->subject($data['details']);
                
        });
          // echo $$request;
        return redirect('ongoingstatus')->with('success','Message Sent!');
    }
```

and my route is

```
Route::post('/messagesend', [UserController::class, 'messagesend'])->middleware(['auth'])->name('messagesend');
```

don't know why i'm getting this error

```
Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\UserController::messagesend(), 1 passed in /home/swit/public_html/manager/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php on line 54 and exactly 2 expected
```

this is my blade.php

```
<form method="POST" action = "{{route('messagesend')}}">
                 @csrf
                 <input type = "hidden" value="{{$email}}" name ="email" />
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="tab-content profile-tab" id="myTabContent">
                            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
                                  
                        <textarea placeholder="Enter Message" name="details" rows="5" cols="60"  id = "details"></textarea><br>
 
                                  <button type = "submit" class = 'btn btn-outline-primary mr-2'>Send Message</button>
                                        
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

please help me out if you know where i'm wrong
thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your route doesn't take any parameter:

```php
Route::post('/messagesend', [UserController::class, 'messagesend'])->middleware(['auth'])->name('messagesend');
```

However, the controller method needs two:

```php
public function messagesend(Request $request, $user_id){
        $data = array('details'=>$request->details,
        'email' =>$user_id->email);
        Mail::send('transactionmessage', $data, function($message) use ($data){
                $message->from ('test@test.com');
                $message->to($request->email);
                $message->subject($data['details']);
                
        });
          // echo $$request;
        return redirect('ongoingstatus')->with('success','Message Sent!');
    }
```

The first argument, `Request $request`, is injected by Laravel using dependency injection.

The second needs to be retrieved from the route, but... their is no parameters.

You have two options here, depending of what you are trying to achieve:

- Adding a parameter to your route:

```php
Route::post('/messagesend/{user_id}', [UserController::class, 'messagesend'])->middleware(['auth'])->name('messagesend');
```

- Remove the argument `$user_id` from your controller method.

Comment: thanks for the reply so if i do this ` Route::post('/messagesend/{user_id}', [UserController::class, 'messagesend'])->middleware(['auth'])->name('messagesend') ` what should i pass to my controller?

Comment: If you add the `user_id` parameter to the route, then you must add it to the url when you call this route. youproject.test//messagesend/12 par exemple, where 12 is the user_id. Then in your controller, `$user_id` will be populated with 12.

Comment: @Tracy if you rearranged your route like that by navigating to `URL/messagesend/{user_id}` (where {user_id} is an integer) the messagesend function should get triggered

Answer (score 0):

All the form does is POST a `Request $request` to your Route. You aren't passing the `messagesend()` function a `$user_id`.

Comment: please how do i do this cause i feel i'm passing the user_id into the messagesend() function already

Comment: @Tracy are you working on localhost or on a remote server?

Comment: @FabioR. remote server

Comment: @Tracy then try to navigate to `url-to-remote-server/messagesend/1` (or any id you currently have in the database) on your browser. This should trigger `messagesend()` function